# The Cross Product of two unit vectors has length $1$: True/False?

Tags: cross-product

Shouldn't equal one always because cross product result is not equal to one all the time yeah?

Started with two random unit vector magnitudes.

Let's say:
$a=\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$,
$b=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\right)$,
$|a|=\frac{1}{2}$,
$|b|=\frac{1}{4}$

Then I cram into cross product $|a||b|\sin(\theta)= \left|\frac{1}{2}\right|\left|\frac{1}{4}\right|\sin(\arcsin(\theta))$.

Comment: Consider two unit vectors that coincide.:)

Comment: It's only true when they are perpendicular.

Comment: The vectors you have chosen are not unit vectors. How can unit vectors have random magnitudes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly this cannot be true, since the cross product of two parallel unit vectors will always be the $0$ vector. That said, the vectors you chose are not unit vectors. Unit vectors have magnitude 1.